# Cocoapods is adding dependencies from other targets to a unit tests of a utility library of ours

Tags: cocoapods, xctest

Using Cocoapods 1.7.5 which we recently updated to from 1.5.3... we think this is a issue new since upgrading our version of Cocoapods.

We are using Cocoapods to manage a handful of pods in our multiple module project that also generates an app from these modules.

Our lowest level module is a utility library we call `Utilitu` and module lives in its own project and is referenced by our workspace. This library does not use any pods however its unit test target does use a network stubbing library.

The following is the entry in our Podfile for this module:

```
target 'Utilitu' do
    project 'Modules/Utilitu/Utilitu.xcodeproj'

    target 'UtilituTests' do
        test_pods
    end
end
```

Earlier in the Podfile we have the following for reuse across targets in the Podfile:

```
def pspdfkit
  pod 'PSPDFKit', podspec: 'Podspecs/PSPDFKit'
end

def common_pods
  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'SSZipArchive'
  pod 'LaunchDarkly'
  pod 'Starscream'
  pspdfkit
end

def test_pods
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
end
```

...and after the `Utilitu` entry we have a handful of additional targets defined in support of those targets needs. We have no custom install steps, etc. in our Podspec.

Anyway the `Pods-Utilitu-UtilituTests` target generated by Cocoapods we are seeing the following being added as `Target Dependencies`. This includes many pods that this target does not use, it only uses `OHHTTPStubs`. Note the `Pods-Utilitu` target has no dependencies as expected.

[image]

Also see the following (Pods-Utilitu-UtilituTests.debug.xccfonig):

```
EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DarklyEventSource" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Eureka" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleUtilities" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/JVFloatLabeledTextField" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/LaunchDarkly" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/MBProgressHUD" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/OHHTTPStubs" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/SSZipArchive" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Starscream" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/nanopb" "${PODS_ROOT}/Crashlytics/iOS" "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/iOS" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/PSPDFKit" "$(PODS_ROOT)/PSPDFKit/**"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1 $(inherited) PB_FIELD_32BIT=1 PB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS=1 PB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DarklyEventSource/DarklyEventSource.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Eureka/Eureka.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/JVFloatLabeledTextField/JVFloatLabeledTextField.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/LaunchDarkly/LaunchDarkly.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/OHHTTPStubs/OHHTTPStubs.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/SSZipArchive/SSZipArchive.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Starscream/Starscream.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/nanopb/nanopb.framework/Headers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Firebase" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop" $(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) '@executable_path/Frameworks' '@loader_path/Frameworks'
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/OHHTTPStubs/OHHTTPStubs.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DarklyEventSource/DarklyEventSource.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Eureka/Eureka.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/JVFloatLabeledTextField/JVFloatLabeledTextField.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/LaunchDarkly/LaunchDarkly.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/SSZipArchive/SSZipArchive.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Starscream/Starscream.framework/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/nanopb/nanopb.framework/Headers" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/OHHTTPStubs" -iframework "${PODS_ROOT}/Crashlytics/iOS" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DarklyEventSource" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Eureka" -iframework "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/iOS" -iframework "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks" -iframework "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleUtilities" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/JVFloatLabeledTextField" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/LaunchDarkly" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/MBProgressHUD" -iframework "${PODS_ROOT}/PSPDFKit" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/SSZipArchive" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Starscream" -iframework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/nanopb"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"c++" -l"iconv" -l"objc" -l"sqlite3" -l"xml2" -l"z" -framework "AVFoundation" -framework "Accelerate" -framework "AssetsLibrary" -framework "AudioToolbox" -framework "CFNetwork" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "CoreImage" -framework "CoreMedia" -framework "CoreTelephony" -framework "CoreText" -framework "Crashlytics" -framework "DarklyEventSource" -framework "Eureka" -framework "FIRAnalyticsConnector" -framework "Fabric" -framework "FirebaseAnalytics" -framework "Foundation" -framework "GLKit" -framework "GoogleAppMeasurement" -framework "GoogleUtilities" -framework "ImageIO" -framework "JVFloatLabeledTextField" -framework "LaunchDarkly" -framework "MBProgressHUD" -framework "MediaPlayer" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "MobileCoreServices" -framework "OHHTTPStubs" -framework "OpenGLES" -framework "PSPDFKit" -framework "PSPDFKitUI" -framework "QuartzCore" -framework "QuickLook" -framework "SSZipArchive" -framework "Security" -framework "Starscream" -framework "StoreKit" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit" -framework "nanopb"
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) -D COCOAPODS
PODS_BUILD_DIR = ${BUILD_DIR}
PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/../..
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/../../Pods
```

**This issues causes 1) the unit tests for the `Utilitu` library to take a lot longer to run since it is compiling many unrelated pods and most recently it is causing a link failure since some dependency is attempting to use something incorrect for that target.**

Example of link failure in this situation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ca9cdf99cfbae2f51d040b73dd242e94.o)
  "_kFIRLoggerAnalytics", referenced from:
      +[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ca9cdf99cfbae2f51d040b73dd242e94.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRAnalyticsConnector_83e864ed9fa8f98ebe9f4740c2eef8b8.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRAnalyticsConnector_83e864ed9fa8f98ebe9f4740c2eef8b8.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ca9cdf99cfbae2f51d040b73dd242e94.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**I have hacked around a bit in our Podfile but I still continue to get the wrong dependencies for the Utilitu unit test target while I believe most other unit test targets don't appear to have a similar issue. So far I cannot figure out what is going wrong in our Podfile, etc.**

The full Podfile...

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

workspace 'OurApp'

def pspdfkit
  pod 'PSPDFKit', podspec: 'Podspecs/PSPDFKit'
end

def common_pods
  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'SSZipArchive'
  pod 'LaunchDarkly'
  pod 'Starscream'
  pspdfkit
end

def test_pods
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
end

target 'Utilitu' do
    project 'Modules/Utilitu/Utilitu.xcodeproj'

    target 'UtilituTests' do
        test_pods
    end
end

target 'Core' do
    project 'Modules/Core/Core.xcodeproj'

    common_pods

    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

    target 'CoreTests' do
      inherit! :complete
      test_pods
    end
end

abstract_target 'App' do
    project 'OurApp/OurApp.xcodeproj'

    common_pods

    target 'OurApp' do
        target 'UnitTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

    target 'AppCore' do
        target 'AppCoreTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

    target 'Camera' do
        target 'CameraTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

    target 'Collaboration' do
        target 'CollaborationTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

    target 'Directory' do
        target 'DirectoryTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

    target 'Drawings' do
        target 'DrawingsTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

    target 'SupplyChain' do
        target 'SupplyChainTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

    target 'Quality' do
        target 'QualityTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

    target 'UI' do
    end

    target 'UIAutomationTests' do
        pod 'Fakery'
    end

    target 'UISnapshotTests' do
        pod 'EarlGrey'
        pod 'iOSSnapshotTestCase'

        inherit! :complete
        test_pods
    end

    target 'Tasks' do
        target 'TasksTests' do
            inherit! :complete
            test_pods
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: On a related note we had to switch to `inherit! :complete` from `inherit! :search_paths` when we upgraded to Cocoapods 1.7.5 to keep unit test targets happy (loading at runtime) despite the target they get injected into having all the libraries needed already linked.

Comment: Opened issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9162